# How to Debug Initialize() in web application

Tags: c#, debugging, iis

I'm trying to create a method that is called when the application is initialized, except when creating a web application, you can only debug it by attaching it to the IIS process (w3wp.exe).

The problem is that this process is only created after initializing the application, which make it impossible to attach the Visual studio debugger to it before calling that method.

Anyone has a solution for this??

Comment: web application can be debuged by pressing f5, can't it? the question is not clear, please make it more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Cassini web server that is included with Visual Studio. In the Web settings for your project you should select **User Visual Studio Development Server**. This will allow you to debug your application by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>.

If you really need to debug inside IIS you can force a debugger break in your `Initialize` method by doing a call to [`Debugger.Break`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx). If you have a debuger installed you will get the option to attach a debugger.

If you a have a very unwieldly application that is hard to debug (besides refactoring it into more managable and testable parts) you can instrument your code with logging. This will allow you to troubleshoot your application even in a production environment. .NET has built-in support for logging and there also exists several good open source frameworks that you can use.

Comment: The application is too big to be started using the Cassini server. It calls a lot of other assemblies divided on separate projects. This might work if the application is small or medium.

I,m still trying to apply the Debugger.Break it might works. Thanks!

Comment: Does it require an extra debugger to be installed or does it work directly with VS debugger? it seams like an alternative to Break point to me, still having the same "attaching" problem.

Comment: I found a really bad solution to do this but at least its working. It consist of throwing application exception where ever I want to check the value of something and send a message with that value. The good news it I'm trying it on a secondary development environment for which I don't really care if it blows up! It may be very risky if I run it in development and I may loose serious data because of non finalized execution.

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou: It works with any debugger registered on the system. If you install Visual Studio it will register itself as a debugger. When `Debugger.Break` is executed you will get a dialog box that allows you to attach to the process. This avoids the "attaching problem".

Answer (score 0):

Set your project to use IIS instead of ASP dev server and create a default web virtual directory that points to your UI dev directories. This is easily done from project properties within Visual Studio.

Build in debug form and then you can either browse your web from IIS or by typing the web directory for the project.

You'll need to register ASP with IIS:

In command window, navigate to "**C:\Windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727**" where C is your boot drive.

then run "**ASPNET_REGIIS -i**" this register ASP.NET with IIS

and then "**ASPNET_REGIIS -ga ASPNET**" this grants IIS access rights to ASP.NET